# How to Alias `python` to Python 2 (`/usr/bin/python2`) on WSL Ubuntu?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, environment-variables, windows-subsystem-for-linux, alias

#### Context:

I am trying to compile [JModelica](https://github.com/JModelica/JModelica) Ubuntu (running on WSL - Windows Subsystem for Linux) and facing a challenge with Python version conflicts. The compilation process requires Python 2, but by default, `python` on my system refers to a Python version managed by `pyenv`, specifically located at `/mnt/c/Users/<userName>/.pyenv/pyenv-win/shims/python`. This setup leads to errors during the JModelica compilation process, such as:

```
make[2]: Entering directory '/mnt/c/dev/JModelica/build'
...
python setup.py install --with_openmp=True ...
/mnt/c/Users/<userName>/.pyenv/pyenv-win/bin/pyenv: 3: cygpath: not found
/mnt/c/Users/<userName>/.pyenv/pyenv-win/bin/pyenv: 3: exec: cmd: not found
make[2]: *** [Makefile:1020: build-python-packages] Error 127
...
```

The compilation fails because it attempts to use the Python version managed by `pyenv`, which seems incompatible with the expected environment. Running `which python` confirms that `python` points to the `pyenv` shim: `/mnt/c/Users/<userName>/.pyenv/pyenv-win/shims/python`.

#### Question:

I have installed Python 2 using `sudo apt install python2`, and `which python2` correctly points to `/usr/bin/python2`. However, I am unsure how to alias `python` to `/usr/bin/python2` across the system or specifically for the JModelica compilation process, bypassing `pyenv`.

I have tried temporarily aliasing `python` to `python2` in my current shell session

```
alias python=/usr/bin/python2
```

and adjusting the `PATH` environment variable so that `/usr/bin` takes precedence over the pyenv shims directory

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
```

but neither approach resolves the issue during the JModelica build process.

Could someone guide me on how to force the Ubuntu operating system to recognize `/usr/bin/python2` as the default `python` interpreter, especially for compiling JModelica, or how to adjust the build process to use the correct Python version?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257156/discussion-on-question-by-foad-s-farimani-how-to-alias-python-to-python-2); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution I have found so far using virtual environments:

- installed pip via `sudo apt install python-pip`
- then `python2 -m pip install virtualenv`
- create a virtual environment with Python 2 isolated from system's default Python `~/.local/bin/virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python2 jmodelica_env`
- then activate the virtual environment to use the isolated Python installation within it `source jmodelica_env/bin/activate`